# PHP Css file using include to add other PHP CSS Files

Tags: php, css, header

There appears to be something bazaar I have just been sent.

There is one main CSS file that is actually a php file with a header to declare itself as CSS. It then includes other CSS also actually PHP files all of which also include that header.

```
header("Content-type: text/css; charset: UTF-8");
```

I can see why they have done this as they are passing PHP variables to the CSS files but suspect that that header only needs to be declared once. The site is causing a number of errors.

Would I be correct that a PHP file that declares that header writes a bit of CSS and then includes other PHP files that also contain CSS, that these other files do not need that header as well.

Comment: yes (now 12 more characters to fill the comment...)

Comment: If the other css file are only included in the main css then yes, otherwise if you need to include somewhere else one of the other css files, you're gonna need the header anyway

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're correct, yes. You only want to send the headers one single time. Instead of having each included PHP file send the headers, I'd just have one send the headers (maybe call it css.php or styles.php or something), and then include in all the other ones that actually contain the CSS. I'd just use that main file for any logic that might be needed to decide what css needs to be included (if it's always the same, maybe it should be a static file anyway).

It'd probably be better to just have static CSS files anyway, to make your site faster and whatnot, but since that wasn't in your question, I assume you're aware of the drawbacks and for whatever reason need to do it this way.

Comment: I prefer dynamic css files because they can be compressed then. I have written a small script that removes all whitespaces and comments what saves me up to 50% data usage.

Comment: This wouldn't solve the problem, bacause he has one css including other css, even if every css includes one css-header file, the header will be included multiple times anyway

Comment: @ByteHamster It sounds like you're just minifying your files - you could do that server side, once, and have the same effect (not including the effect of caching and gzip, etc)

Comment: @Phate01 Maybe I'm misunderstanding (it is morning, and my coffee isn't done yet) - I imagined this as one file just going through and including blocks of text, concatenating them, and then just sending it to the browser at once. Unless I'm missing something, I don't see a problem there.

Comment: @Mike I have never realized that, thanks. :D Will do that in my next project.

Comment: @ByteHamster - You're welcome! Just look around for "css minifier". You had the right idea entirely, it's done all over the place for exactly the reason you said, except now you only have to do it once, instead of every request. There's all kinds of tools built for it.

Comment: @Mike: Your answer wasn't initially clear to me, here is almost 4 PM and I'm definitely gonna have a coffee

Comment: @Phate01 No problem, I honestly expect the best answer to all of this is "don't do that, use static css files" anyway, and that causes some confusion.